# How to find symbols surrounded by plusses

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a little code with regex (I use findall method):

```py
import re
print(re.findall(r'(\+[a-z]\+)', '+f+d+c+#+f+'))
```

I want to get a symbols like this: `+f+`, `+d+`, `+c+`, `+f+` (symbols surrounded by pluses).
Tell me what I should pay attention to.

Comment: Do you want to match `f` `d` `c` `f` or `+f+` `+d+` `+c+` `+f+`

Answer (score 2):

You can use positive lookaheads and lookbehinds to assert the presence of a `+` character without actually consuming it:

```
>>> print(re.findall(r'((?<=\+)[a-z]+(?=\+))', '+f+d+c+#+f+'))
['f', 'd', 'c', 'f']
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (use look-behind to not consume the search string):

```py
import re

print(re.findall(r"(?<=(\+[a-z]\+))", "+f+d+c+#+f+"))
```

Prints:

```
['+f+', '+d+', '+c+', '+f+']
```

Comment: Sneaky, I didn't know you could put a capture group in a look-behind.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Yes, you can even nest them (e.g. `r"(?<=(?<=(\+))[a-z](?=(\+)))"`) but if it's useful... that's other question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a *matching* pattern, rather than a *capture* pattern, to evaluate values that over-lap.

```
(?<=\+)[a-z](?=\+)
```

This will return all 4 values.

```
['f', 'd', 'c', 'f']
```